# Xamarin MVVM Data Binding through ViewModel while having class with an object list inside it

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, binding

My problem is that I have a class Location, class LocationsDb and within LocationsDb I have a public List with hardcoded data in it. And now I'm having trouble with my ViewModel class while trying to bind data from List which is inside LocationsDb class. I want my Listview to show only cities. What am I doing wrong with my code?

Location class

```
public class Location
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public int emptySpaces { get; set; }

    public Location(string city, string street, int emptySpaces)
    {
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
        this.emptySpaces = emptySpaces;
    }
}
```

LocationsDb class

```
public class LocationsDb
{
    public List<Location> Locations = new List<Location>
    {
        new Location("Vilnius", "Ateities g. 91", 5),
        new Location("Vilnius", "S. Nėries g. 91", 10),
        new Location("Vilnius", "Lukiškių g. 6", 1),
        new Location("Vilnius", "Dominikonų g. 4", 0),
        new Location("Kaunas", "Jonavos g. 1", 8),
        new Location("Kaunas", "Vytauto pr. 24", 3),
        new Location("Kaunas", "Žemaičių g. 31B", 0),
        new Location("Kaunas", "Ateities g. 91", 5),
        new Location("Klaipėda", "Smiltelės g. 2A", 13),
        new Location("Klaipėda", "Žvejų g. 27", 7),
        new Location("Klaipėda", "Minijos g. 90", 0),
        new Location("Klaipėda", "Bangų g. 5", 0),
    };

    public List<Location> GetLocations()
    {
        return this.Locations;
    }
}
```

ViewModel class

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Location> AllCities { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Location> allCities { get { return AllCities; } }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        AllCities = new ObservableCollection<Location>(new LocationsDb().Locations);
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ParkingApp.Views.MainPage"
         ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
         >
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Select City" 
               BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
               HeightRequest="50" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="30"/>

        <ListView x:Name="CitiesListview" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllCities}" SeparatorColor="Black">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding city}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Sorry, first time here, won't happen again :)

Comment: where are you assigning the BindingContext for your page?   What I can see of your code looks OK.  You haven't really described what the specific problem you're having is.  "I'm having trouble with my ViewModel class" is not very descriptive

Comment: I’m trying to solve how to display only cities inside my listview and I don’t understand what am I doing wrong because while debugging i can see that my ObservableCollection gets all objects from inside LocationDb list but it’s not displaying anything on the screen with data binding. And oh, I forgot to paste that, but there is BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel() on MainPage.cs

Comment: try assigning a height to your ListView, or use a StackLayout instead of a Grid

Comment: But overall the code is correct and it should display my items, right?

Comment: yes, as I said before it appears correct.  The Grid might not be allocating space for your LIstView, making it appear empty.

Comment: Your code looks good. Only remove ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" and check once. There might be some problem i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your code to binding observablecollection to ListView, having no problem. I don't change any code for ContentPage.xaml

Please check my ContentPage.cs:

```
public partial class Page8 : ContentPage
{     
    public Page8()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Location> AllCities { get; set; }
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        AllCities = new ObservableCollection<Location>(new LocationsDb().Locations);
    }
}
```

About ListView binding, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has gone wrong but the next time I started my application it was working like a charm. No changes with my code. So I don't know, maybe some kind of Binding delay or bug, but the code was fine and my listview displayed what I want.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solve your problem now.